# Finding the the value for a key in a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, key-value

I would like to know how to check the value of a specific key in a HashMap.
 For example if the HashMap `map` contains the key `myKey` then how do I find the value of this key?

Comment: did you read the javadoc?

Comment: Follow this tutorial : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm

Comment: Did you see the [`get(K)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) method in the docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [the documentation of HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) .

To answer your question, you are looking for the [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) method: `public V get(Object key)`

Use it like this:

`map.get(keyName)` will return the value of the key `keyName`.

Answer (score 3):

map.get("Key")

if "Key" is not present in the map, the result is null; for map implementations that allow null values you then have to use map.containsKey("Key") to distinguish a "null" value from no value.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a HashMap:

```
HashMap <String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

if (map.containsKey("myKey")) {
    int value= map.get("myKey");
}
```